# AWS EC2 setting up auto scale

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I am trying to setup auto scaling on an existing server using EC2 but using an existing instance.
AWS's docs have the option --instance-id but that option is not listed/found in the CLI version I have. Nor is the as-attach-instance command.

How can I setup to monitor an existing instance?

The only alternative I have is having the auto scaling group create a min number of 1 instance and work off that but I'd rather avoid it if I can.
Also, can I make sure auto-scaling will launch instances using the next available IP and not a random one?

Comment: I found the issue. My CLIs were outdated.

Comment: I am still not sure how to have auto scaling assign a specific range of private IPs. I want to use x.x.x.150-200. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Creating your autoscale group so that it launches into the VPC network with range you want should do it.

[image: Autoscale]